# How to configure ssh agent service and keys for git deployments using non-root user?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, sshd, ssh-agent

I had a problem when doing deployments (using non-root user):

```
$> git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

After some digging here and there I've figured out the workaround that works for me:

```
$> eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 61080
$> ssh-add ~/.ssh/deploymapr
Identity added: /home/mapr/.ssh/deploymapr (/home/mapr/.ssh/deploymapr)
$> git pull
remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
⋮
```

Now that I do the deployments quite often - I need to repeat steps above each and every time I log on to the deployment server which is a bit of a hassle.

I'm sure there's better, elegant way to configure this for a regular user (and I'm not talking about adding these two lines to `~/.bashrc`…). Any ideas?

**Update**: As per answers below, I've configured my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
stat -c "%A %a %n" ~/.gitconfig ~/.ssh/deploymapr ~/.ssh/config
-rw-rw-r-- 664 /home/mapr/.gitconfig
-rw------- 600 /home/mapr/.ssh/deploymapr
-rw-r--r-- 644 /home/mapr/.ssh/config
```

but I still get error (when not running workaround=the two commands above, manually):

```
$ git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the information in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host hostname
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploymapr
```

Or move the key to the standard location (`~/.ssh/id_rsa` or respective by manual page).

Comment: `Bad owner or permissions on /home/mapr/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: set `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config`. openssh is pretty strict about privileges. And check that the file is owned by you.

Comment: still doesn't work. I think the issue here is the fact that the solution you give doesn't cater for the equivalent of  `eval $(ssh-agent)` which I also need to do…

Comment: what for? What you mean by does not work? Post more details to edited question. Certainly you need to adjust hostname to the real host that stores your git repository (or remove that line completely).

Comment: that's all done (created `~/.ssh/config`). I still need to perform the two steps as in question, otherwise I get: `Permission denied (publickey).¶
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.¶
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: what should be `alias` used in `~/.ssh/config`? That value must correlate with something right?

Comment: It does not have to be alias. You can put there direct hostname. You can find hostname of your git server in the `.git/config` (in your repository). Or it is the host you used when you did `git clone`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a SSH config file

> Create a SSH config file mechanisms to create aliases for your various identities.
>
> You can construct a SSH config file using many parameters and different approaches.
>
> The format for the alias entries use in this example is:
>
> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName bitbucket.org 
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```
>
> To create a config file for two identities (workid and personalid), you would do the following:

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host workid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid

Host personalid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately. I think the issue here is the fact that the solution you give doesn't cater for the equivalent of  `eval $(ssh-agent)` which I also need to do…

Comment: You heed it if you need to start the ssh agent 'eval $(ssh-agent)'

Comment: yes, but my question is really how to configure system so the user doesn't have to do `eval $(ssh-agent)` each and every time…